# How to remove null values in query using CONCAT with CASE statement

Tags: mysql, database

I want to ignore null value from query  .

I tried with case statement inside concat but its give me null values 
The table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `UserInfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext NOT NULL,
  `created_on` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=111 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  

insert  into `UserInfo`(`id`,`user_id`,`key`,`value`,`created_on`,`updated_on`,`status`) 
values (69,11132,'country','India','','',1),(67,11132,'city','Gurgaon','','',1),(68,11132,'state','Haryana','','',1),(66,11132,'address','CyberHub','','',1),(64,11131,'state','Delhi','','',1),(65,11131,'country','India','','',1),(63,11131,'city','','','',1),(62,11131,'address','Lajpat Nagar','','',1),(60,11130,'state','Haryana','','',1),(61,11130,'country','India','','',1),(58,11130,'address','','','',1),(59,11130,'city','Gurgaon','','',1),(787,11130,'password','0192023a7bbd73250516f069df18b500','30-03-2016 06:58:18','30-03-2016 06:58:18',1),(788,11131,'password','04d237e63ebc1acbb3fcacf3e1a846cb','30-03-2016 06:58:18','26-04-2016 07:46:33',1),(789,11132,'password','0192023a7bbd73250516f069df18b500','30-03-2016 06:58:18','24-05-2016 11:47:35',1),(1123,11130,'parent','0','','',1),(1124,11131,'parent','0','','',1),(1125,11132,'parent','0','','',1),(2036,11136,'gcm_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc','04-05-2016 06:01:07','04-05-2016 06:01:07',1),(2035,11136,'push_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc:APA91bFO-hLW5uQqDQTABkilyOd9MzuMRhQMI8uNLRGh4fjaq3Bk1OvFmb7QFVKYpqqJZFPQ78Y1h0349IZuxq0EcxZ8VCHJOTOhhsqi1VxQ2A7TVLY-phDcN6sj80x8R7KoOocQKPLl','04-05-2016 06:01:07','04-05-2016 06:01:07',1),(2993,11570,'transaction_limit','100','16-09-2016 10:34:13','16-09-2016 10:34:13',1),(2992,11570,'otp','461178','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2991,11570,'password','1e28284f59e926547bb6793ad8723722','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2990,11570,'imei','353918057482479','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2989,11570,'push_id','dGxCE33MJgg:APA91bFCzSkvIDEcZcgmmSxVocFNZfLI8owLsdElmF-Et0wUH0mxUbQ9mIZDMjlhqClTOYiSxhSaVBdESwJW6J58hsyEF0LUMgXRTGdnEwWdbHJmm3EZuHDHzniMaJGcCKvALrcxtQt8','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2987,11570,'gender','Male','16-09-2016 10:32:48','16-09-2016 10:32:48',1),(2026,11136,'gcm_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc','03-05-2016 06:28:52','03-05-2016 06:28:52',1),(2025,11136,'push_id','fLJ8vwS5yWc:APA91bFO-hLW5uQqDQTABkilyOd9MzuMRhQMI8uNLRGh4fjaq3Bk1OvFmb7QFVKYpqqJZFPQ78Y1h0349IZuxq0EcxZ8VCHJOTOhhsqi1VxQ2A7TVLY-phDcN6sj80x8R7KoOocQKPLl','03-05-2016 06:28:52','03-05-2016 06:28:52',1),(2024,11136,'gcm_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms','02-05-2016 17:02:39','02-05-2016 17:02:39',1),(2023,11136,'push_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms:APA91bHA-a_joHtzEBgoAPRxRCXObeJLlCCNSxlCM-jBZKvSUEFvhLZEyqPbbsIDyWc2emZa1yBerOQLGXgzzNKZmcJYCgcF8KBdm9McVBiDKzU_OthjGnROZyTC5EvnI7Z4QivXnokA','02-05-2016 17:02:39','02-05-2016 17:02:39',1),(2022,11136,'gcm_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms','02-05-2016 16:38:55','02-05-2016 16:38:55',1),(2020,11136,'gcm_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ','02-05-2016 16:37:53','02-05-2016 16:37:53',1),(2021,11136,'push_id','cU6PMImJ9Ms:APA91bHA-a_joHtzEBgoAPRxRCXObeJLlCCNSxlCM-jBZKvSUEFvhLZEyqPbbsIDyWc2emZa1yBerOQLGXgzzNKZmcJYCgcF8KBdm9McVBiDKzU_OthjGnROZyTC5EvnI7Z4QivXnokA','02-05-2016 16:38:55','02-05-2016 16:38:55',1),(2019,11136,'push_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ:APA91bGskmvA5VVmxozMHKX3qHc16bdmk9h5gFTEPP8uFUYsO-doGCnkTE-ZtpMGeuuk2YCt3Ja56ey7nIga6aO7wpof2fI5zcgYdFACKvkcddNAlY4UhIO39tfyG3m4DZkmaLqw2Kxu','02-05-2016 16:37:53','02-05-2016 16:37:53',1),(2018,11136,'gcm_id','djRRW-PrS2Q','02-05-2016 16:30:02','02-05-2016 16:30:02',1),(2016,11136,'gcm_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ','02-05-2016 16:25:00','02-05-2016 16:25:00',1),(2017,11136,'push_id','djRRW-PrS2Q:APA91bFbB5SO0wY2TlGCZBmgbZUr0c1FXH5FE22YxOCf4tA7uM1V45T2cTY1aitIQKrf1bjrPB-zZUCDPNdL8-2SYnEawrFTdVjL5w1VuVI2kA89ixlK6jlpmNOoJ7wQnWqQoCFkcd9_','02-05-2016 16:30:02','02-05-2016 16:30:02',1),(2015,11136,'push_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ:APA91bGskmvA5VVmxozMHKX3qHc16bdmk9h5gFTEPP8uFUYsO-doGCnkTE-ZtpMGeuuk2YCt3Ja56ey7nIga6aO7wpof2fI5zcgYdFACKvkcddNAlY4UhIO39tfyG3m4DZkmaLqw2Kxu','02-05-2016 16:25:00','02-05-2016 16:25:00',1),(2014,11136,'gcm_id','djRRW-PrS2Q','01-05-2016 07:38:26','01-05-2016 07:38:26',1),(2013,11136,'push_id','djRRW-PrS2Q:APA91bFbB5SO0wY2TlGCZBmgbZUr0c1FXH5FE22YxOCf4tA7uM1V45T2cTY1aitIQKrf1bjrPB-zZUCDPNdL8-2SYnEawrFTdVjL5w1VuVI2kA89ixlK6jlpmNOoJ7wQnWqQoCFkcd9_','01-05-2016 07:38:26','01-05-2016 07:38:26',1),(2012,11136,'gcm_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ','01-05-2016 07:29:00','01-05-2016 07:29:00',1),(2011,11136,'push_id','c2sOUeSpIuQ:APA91bGskmvA5VVmxozMHKX3qHc16bdmk9h5gFTEPP8uFUYsO-doGCnkTE-ZtpMGeuuk2YCt3Ja56ey7nIga6aO7wpof2fI5zcgYdFACKvkcddNAlY4UhIO39tfyG3m4DZkmaLqw2Kxu','01-05-2016 07:29:00','01-05-2016 07:29:00',1),(2010,11439,'otp','467957','01-05-2016 07:04:42','16-08-2016 10:48:09',0),(2009,11438,'otp','631866','30-04-2016 09:36:54','06-05-2016 13:32:15',0),(2008,11438,'otp','586481','30-04-2016 09:22:55','06-05-2016 13:32:15',0),(2007,11438,'otp','971411','30-04-2016 09:19:52','06-05-2016 13:32:15',0),(2006,11136,'gcm_id','eNJISa-1OGA','30-04-2016 09:05:22','30-04-2016 09:05:22',1),(2005,11136,'push_id','eNJISa-1OGA:APA91bGB6m0d-RzoFUvw1SRsCIOEvfO3BjLUiMsZRdHnHlEGq6QKV9sVqCdLai25_dxTvUeuQVzFU5scKCaPvlDaG_VZ-V51t1AG4EEAtJdjGNQwhITF2eh0E24D_J9vPCQ3nIzanq8f','30-04-2016 09:05:22','30-04-2016 09:05:22',1),(2004,11445,'transaction_limit','2000','30-04-2016 09:03:41','30-04-2016 09:03:41',1),(2003,11445,'otp','230253','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(2002,11445,'password','25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(2001,11445,'push_id','ccPZg_PD7bo:APA91bFrUK8JPZfI6tSBKDgETeeI_aE6RA-FTFh6pS4fluVv6jHIVKUyDAEurIJWo49nWa52q6Zas7F2DI_KNkDX-HVq_TXuO36dRN9JditQVGR9HUq8avS5QEzYA2gwYjyo7Bosrsyz','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(2000,11445,'gcm_id','ccPZg_PD7bo','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(1999,11445,'gender','Male','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(1998,11445,'bank_name','DCB Bank','30-04-2016 09:02:35','30-04-2016 09:02:35',1),(1997,11136,'gcm_id','cXK3F2L7Fcw','30-04-2016 08:37:01','30-04-2016 08:37:01',1)
```

I tried with query but its produce null column value as well
I want to ignore null value

```
 SELECT
  CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN ui.key='gender' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN ui.key='password' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN ui.key='transaction_limit' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END
  ) AS test,
  ui.id,ui.user_id,ui.key,ui.value
FROM UserInfo ui 
WHERE ui.user_id=11445

Result :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test    id   user_id    key                 value
2000    2004  11445    transaction_limit    2000
        2003  11445    otp                  230253
25d55ad 2002  11445    password             25d55ad..
        2001  11445    push_id              ccPZg_P..
        2000  11445    gcm_id               ccPZg_PD7bo
Male    1999  11445    gender               Male
        1998  11445 bank_name               DCB Bank

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Desire Result :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test    id   user_id    key                 value
2000    2004  11445    transaction_limit    2000
25d55ad 2002  11445    password             25d55ad..
Male    1999  11445    gender               Male

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You can use coalesce function to replace null value with any user defined value.

Comment: I tried with coalesce but It messed up result

Comment: test column having value with matching field and unmatched field as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the wron answer:

you can add Having:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN ui.key='gender' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN ui.key='password' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN ui.key='transaction_limit' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END
  ) AS test,
  ui.id,ui.user_id,ui.key,ui.value
FROM UserInfo ui 
WHERE ui.user_id=11445
HAVING test <> '';
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   CONCAT(
    ->     CASE WHEN ui.key='gender' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    ->     CASE WHEN ui.key='password' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END,
    ->     CASE WHEN ui.key='transaction_limit' THEN ui.value ELSE '' END
    ->   ) AS test,
    ->   ui.id,ui.user_id,ui.key,ui.value
    -> FROM UserInfo ui
    -> WHERE ui.user_id=11445
    -> HAVING test <> '';
+----------------------------------+------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| test                             | id   | user_id | key               | value                            |
+----------------------------------+------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
| 2000                             | 2004 |   11445 | transaction_limit | 2000                             |
| 25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad | 2002 |   11445 | password          | 25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad |
| Male                             | 1999 |   11445 | gender            | Male                             |
+----------------------------------+------+---------+-------------------+----------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: thanks dear. It is working. You save my amount of time. Could you please let me know why "test" column not working in where clause instead of having ?

Comment: @oxygen - with WHERE you only reduce the rows that you use in your query and with having you reduce the reseltset after the query. so with havig you can count or concat all rows and after that you can recude this reseltset like HAVING count > 5 or something else

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CONCAT_WS** instead of **CONCAT** . The first arg by **CONCAT_WS** ist the separetor

**sample**

```
mysql> select CONCAT('a','b',NULL,'d','e');
+------------------------------+
| CONCAT('a','b',NULL,'d','e') |
+------------------------------+
| NULL                         |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> select CONCAT_WS(',','a','b',NULL,'d','e');
+-------------------------------------+
| CONCAT_WS(',','a','b',NULL,'d','e') |
+-------------------------------------+
| a,b,d,e                             |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Manual:**

> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special
>   form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of
>   the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be
>   concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the
>   arguments.
>
> If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL; all other NULL values
>   are skipped. This makes CONCAT_WS() suitable when you want to
>   concatenate some values and avoid losing all information if one of
>   them is NULL.

Comment: This is not working as per my desire solution while I go with GROUP_CONCAT it considering null values

Comment: @oxygen - i have add a new answer for you - sorry for the first one